# Docker MYSQL '[2002] Connection refused'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker

I was trying out Docker for the first time. Got a LEMP stack up and running, but I can't connect to the MYSQL Database. Not on my Symfony application, not on PHPMyAdmin. The applications are returning the following error code:

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
phpfpm:
    build: phpfpm/
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
mysql:
  image: mariadb
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8183:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: admin
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

Dockerfile PHPFPM:

```
    FROM php:fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-enable opcache
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql
```

GitHub URL: https://github.com/MolengraafFrank/DockerSymfony

Could someone help me out? Thank you for your time.

Comment: please add the contents of phpfpm/ lib, since without it we cannot test your docker-compose setup.

Comment: I have added the Dockerfile. Is that enough?

Comment: Does you docker-compose up command finish successfully? When I try to run it the nginx container raises an error and the process crashes.

Comment: Yaron, I will commit my whole dockerproject to git today. I will post the url here! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yaron, this is the url to the GitHub repository: https://github.com/MolengraafFrank/DockerSymfony.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The '[2002] Connection refused' means you can reach the database server, but you don't have right access for the user (in your case admin). By default mariadb have a root user with the password given by MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD and this user can connect from any server (%).

If you want use an over login to your databases, you have to create it in the databases server with the right granting on databases from chosen locations.

**The problem here is that you have named your database server as 'mysql' (service name in the docker-compose file). But by default phpmyadmin tries to connect to a database server named 'db'. Adding `PMA_HOST: mysql` under the environment section of the phpmyadmin service will resolve this problem.**

---

I think that MYSQL_USERNAME and PMA_ARBITRARY are useless if you work with default configuration (connection with root to your databases server)

Comment: This works, but my application in PHPFPM still can't connect to the database.

Comment: Edited the PHPFPM docker-compose. It works for 100% now!

Answer (score 33):

I had this challenge because I am running 3 different containers with different IP Addresses

```
db - 172.18.0.3 - container for MYSQL
app - 172.18.0.2 - container for Laravel app
```

so I fixed it by editing my Laravel .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.18.0.3
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=username
...
```

To get your containers Ip addresses. From your docker host

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

UPDATED:
For latest docker versions and based on the services name, "mysql", in your docker-compose.yml

```
mysql:
  image: mariadb
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
```

You can try this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=username
```

DB_HOST is the name of MySQL service name defined in docker-compose.yml

Comment: This solved to me, thank you. But there is a way to use just "localhost"?

Comment: It may work but you should know that the ip address will change  on every restart, therefore isn't a consistent solution.

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to connect to the mysql instance using mysql command line tool, this is the command I used - `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1`, and the entering the admin password. Is that a sufficient solution for you?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was running `mysql` in a docker container whose port was mapped to the host mac (`3306:3306`). I tried connecting to this database from a `phpmyadmin` docker container using 127.0.0.1 . But it won't work because the `localhost` on the `phpmyadmin` docker container does not have the required `mysql` running.

To connect to the host from docker network

```
docker.for.mac.host.internal
```

[Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) [Docker Compose Networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: This works for me using a mysql on host and connecting from docker.

Answer (score 1):

For my instance, the issue was with **port mapping** somehow.

In my case it was `3307:3306`, as soon as I changed it to `3307` on the right side as well, I could connect to the DB instance.

Comment: Thank you, you save me the rest of my day trying to figure out the issue! :)
There must be something to do with port 3306 refusing any connection to it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why your connexion failed, you can use in your terminal php **`artisan tinker`** and then
like

```
DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

Unfortunately this will only give you a part of the error.
**Quit tinker** and then use this command **`php artisan db`** will give you more information like database type, host, port, ad user about the issue.

Like this one

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (61)

   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException 

  The command "'mysql' '--host=127.0.0.1' '--port=3306' '--user=root' '--default-character-set=utf8mb4' 'laravel'" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /Users/Dev/Documents/www/laravel_docker/src/addressAPI

Output:
================


Error Output:
================

  at vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:270
    266▕      */
    267▕     public function mustRun(callable $callback = null, array $env = []): self
    268▕     {
    269▕         if (0 !== $this->run($callback, $env)) {
  ➜ 270▕             throw new ProcessFailedException($this);
    271▕         }
    272▕ 
    273▕         return $this;
    274▕     }

      +14 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

This will not give you the answer on what is wrong, but at least you can understand why your config is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### ⚠ This answer is an additional hint for a special case!

In the case of sudden error such that. i.e.**everything had been worked fine before** *but after* an *update* of **Docker** during stopping some container or something like that, the **IP** of the MySQL container may be changed and it may lead to such errors. In my case, Laravel .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.19.0.3
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=superSecret
```

and for Yii2 app config/db.php

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=172.19.0.3;dbname=db_name2',
    'username' => 'db_user',
    'password' => 'superSecret',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I got such error for both apps, after they were working fine. However, running `docker inspect mysql` where mysql is the name of the mysql container shows in the network section:

```
...
"Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
...
```

So changing the the host IP in the configs from `172.19.0.3` to `172.19.0.2` solves the issue in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while trying to dockerize my laravel application. I seemed to have this issue with `mysql:8.0` but not with `mysql:5.7`. However, I did need version 8. So I just switched to `mariadb:10.4` instead, which solved this issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

you need to link the phpfpm container to mysql.

Comment: Thank you. I've done this, but I am still getting the [2002] Connection refused error.

Comment: @FrankMolengraaf if you've made any changes to your docker-compose.yml please update your question with them

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - according to the shared configuration, the container for phpMyAdmin is properly linked

Answer (score -2):

Adding `DB_READ_HOST=db` solved this problem for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).