# Docker Stack: Setup Adminer and MySQL Connection Refused

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, adminer

## Story

I am new to docker. While reading some docs I bumped into [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer/) and followed its quick database system setup example.

> Example `stack.yml` for `adminer`.

I then run `docker stack deploy -c stack.yml adminer` and get the following screen served on `localhost:8080`:

[image: Adminer UI]

## Problem

The docs stop right there. And I had no luck connecting to MySQL in this docker setup. When trying any addresses (`0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1`, `localhost`) in **Server** field I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

#### Thoughts

The example code has the following comment:

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
```

So I fill `root` and `example` as **user** and **password** respectively. But if the given message would mean [I have the wrong credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561433/docker-mysql-2002-connection-refused#answer-40611827), which would be the right password for **root** user?

Would any of you people spot problems on the supplied docs?

Could any host system issues be interfering with my setup?

#### Environment

- Windows 10 Pro (up to date)
- Docker for Windows
- PowerShell

What other information can I give you?

Comment: Using that stack the database server would be `db`.

Comment: windows is really not the platform to run docker on... Your problem could be caused by a number of things. First, try publishing your `3306` port.

Comment: @AlexKarshin `ports: - 3306:3306` on **db**?

Comment: @ShawnC. When putting `db` as server I get parsing error.