# Laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, laravel

I have checked this issue on this forum but couldn't solve it.

**.env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=channelable
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

**and database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'channelable'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

I am sure that the database username and password are: **root**

I use `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` commands but still show me a error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
> where table_schema = channelable and table_name = migrations and
> table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Try using `localhost` instead of IP `127.0.0.1` for hostname

Comment: Tired but still showing me that same error.

Comment: Have you check and follow mention steps in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges

Comment: do you use docker ?

Comment: Yes, on my project folder I can see docker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker MYSQL '\[2002\] Connection refused'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561433/docker-mysql-2002-connection-refused)

Comment: E.g. on Mac Docker instead of `localhost` we must use `docker.for.mac.localhost` as `localhost` points to internal IP of Docker, and not to internal IP of machine (host)

Comment: What you mean `i can see docker`? are you serving your application by running `php artisan serve` or `docker compose ...`? If you're using first one, then you're not probably using docker at all, you just got it in your project or etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo mysql -u root

mysql> ALTER USER the_user IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'the_password';
```

Comment: I got this: https://prnt.sc/-ixVb9T7PZoP

Comment: Create a new user with all privileges and try again

Comment: I don't understand. Something is wrong: https://prnt.sc/rVfRSlPvWk0F and got this error: ` SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'shibbir'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = channelable and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Comment: Have you tried executing with the host? ALTER USER root@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';

Comment: If you run the command above, it defaults to users with host "%". Therefore, when creating a user, you can specify '%' as the host, thereby assigning the user to any host

Comment: I am trying the command.

Comment: Ah no luck, can we start chat?

Comment: I had an identical problem, I solved the problem with the above command. Thought it would help you. Now I don't know how to help you, I tried))

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue few weeks ago and even after changing the user details from terminal, the error persistsed.

Below was how I resolved it. Enclose the DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD values in double quotes as shown below:

```
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD="root"
```

Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

this error happens when you are providing wrong username or passowd to the .env setting for the mysqli driver to connect to mysql i dont thinks by adding
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD="root"
check your credentials or reset your password and then try again